# Git not recognizing rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I installed the table_builder plugin from https://github.com/p8/table_builder, followed the directions at the bottom titled **For a pre rails 3.0 table_builder:** which works great.

The problem is since I checked out a branch of it, when I try to commit this to MY GIT repo, it doesnt think there are files even there.. git status diplays nothing, git add wont add the files..

Any suggestions as to how I can get this committed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you cloned the plugin directly into your own repository and you now have the plugin repository within your repository?

A git repository will by default ignore any other repositories and their working directories that are located within it.

If so, you have (at least) two options:

- Clone the plugin elsewhere, and then
  copy the necessary files into your
  repository
- Clone the plugin into your repository
  and then delete the plugin's .git
  folder

There are other ways to manage this with git-submodule but I'm not an expert on that so I defer to someone with more knowledge.

Comment: deleted it, did a git checkout to desktop, copied it in, added as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.gitignore` file in your project root folder. If `git status` doesn't see the files and `git add` won't add them, it's most likely because they're being specifically ignored.

Comment: no, checked that, I would have had to specifically add it, its not there. Both of them are hosted on git hub, and the fact that I had to use 'git checkout' i think is the culprit..

Comment: In `vendor/plugins/table_builder` you should be able to delete the `.git` folder, which will make it lose its status as a git repository. This shouldn't be the problem, but it worth a shot...

Comment: no such folder exists (yes, i've shown hidden files/folders, including browsing in transmit which does it automatically)